# Tool or plugin to extract class and all of its dependencies from VS project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, plugins, dependencies, scanning

I have a very large project with lots of files. I need to extract only a few classes into a separate DLL, but the problem is that the classes have many dependencies on other files. Trying to make it manually, I've already spent several hours, and still there are limitless errors related to missing files. Is there any solution to automate this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a tool that will automate the whole process, but you could use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) to help you.

Starting with the class that you want to extract, NDepend can generate a list telling you that class's dependencies, and the dependencies of those classes, and so on.