# How do I extract a single class plus all its dependencies from a library?

Tags: java

I got a big Java library but only need a small portion of it. How would I extract the main class and all of its dependencies? An automated solution would be preferred, but I can also live with something that generates a list of files I need to extract (I don't want to write that *something* myself ;-)).

This is similar to [Tool or plugin to extract class and all of its dependencies from VS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068944/tool-or-plugin-to-extract-class-and-all-of-its-dependencies-from-vs-project) - I just need it for Java (IDE in use is Eclipse).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a tool called [autojar](http://autojar.sourceforge.net/en_d/index.html).
It works.