# How do I extract a class or classes, plus all its/their dependencies, from a java library (with source available)?

Tags: java, dependencies

I have a large Java library but only need a small portion of it. How would I extract one (or more) class(es) that I want to use directly, plus all of its/their dependencies?

(An automated solution would be preferred, but I can also live with something that generates a list of files I need to manually extract).

This is a re-submission of [How do I extract a single class plus all its dependencies from a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408620/how-do-i-extract-a-single-class-plus-all-its-dependencies-from-a-library) from 2011. The answer from 2011 no longer works (at least, not with java 8).

Comment: Are you using maven, gradle, or nothing? Do you want to extract them from the jar/war/ear archive? What IDE you want to use?

Comment: I was hoping for a tool that would analyse the source files themselves--and that would presumably be the most general tool, too. But I _am_ using maven; and I don't want to extract .class files from a .jar, I need to work with the source code. Thanks.

Comment: So, given a bunch of .java files it must return the minimal subset of .java required to compile one or more of them?

Comment: Is there any solution that works for java 8 ?